# acf function using group_by in R

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, cross-correlation

I have a dataframe with 5 variables. These data are for several years and I have grouped them season wise. I want to compute the cross correlation and lag correlation among the 5 variables for every season. How can I do this using acf function in R? I found some examples but they are giving the correlations only between two variables using the 'cor' function or 'lag' function. Since I have 5 variables, I can use acf function which can give cross and lag correlations among all the variables, but I don't know how to use it with the group_by in dplyr package. I think there must be elegant way to do this in R. The dataframe looks like:

```
 Season   Res1      Res2       Res3      Res4      Res5
 summer   4.4336    4.8965    31.4385   -0.6288   -1.1579
 summer   2.5130    3.7541    -2.2947   12.4083   -0.6241
      .        .         .          .         .         .                         
      .        .         .          .         .         .
```

For example, I can compute the correlations using acf for the whole data. If I take the 5 variables as matrix Resdf then I can do it like this:

`M<-acf(Resdf,lag.max =1,type ="correlation",plot=TRUE)`

This will give me the cross correlation and lag-1 correlations among the 5 variables. I can extract the cross correlations as `M0<-M$acf[1,,]` and lag-1 correlations as `M1<-M$acf[2,,]` which will give the 5x5 matrices like this:

```
>M0
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,]  1.0000000  0.8606853  0.0500022 -0.3440501 -0.1709415
[2,]  0.8606853  1.0000000  0.2662694 -0.5228191 -0.2376250
[3,]  0.0500022  0.2662694  1.0000000 -0.5710574 -0.2005080
[4,] -0.3440501 -0.5228191 -0.5710574  1.0000000  0.2163159
[5,] -0.1709415 -0.2376250 -0.2005080  0.2163159  1.0000000
```

and lag-1 correlations as

```
> M1
            [,1]          [,2]       [,3]       [,4]        [,5]
[1,]  0.72688806  0.7648605807  0.2416748 -0.4725366 -0.24970773
[2,]  0.66442943  0.7413684874  0.3125458 -0.4918965 -0.25046233
[3,] -0.06882386  0.0002300747  0.2523668 -0.1015463 -0.01341474
[4,] -0.13060710 -0.2369795768 -0.3061068  0.4032776  0.12751785
[5,] -0.10527689 -0.1044584694 -0.1070397  0.1025203  0.33448922
```

Is there any way I can use acf in this way to get the correlation matrices for the 4 seasons?

Comment: Are you sure you want `autocorrelation` function? Could you provide an example of how you would compute the autocorrelation of your data, and the expected output?

Comment: @ChiPak: I edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example data following your format:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Season=c(rep("spring",3),rep("summer",3)),
                 Res1=rnorm(6))

df1 <- df %>% mutate(Res2=Res1+(rnorm(6)*0.1),
                     Res3=Res1+(rnorm(6)*0.2),
                     Res4=Res1+(rnorm(6)*0.3),
                     Res5=Res1+(rnorm(6)*0.4))
```

Use `tidyverse` `nest` to perform 'complex' operations on a grouped data frame. I perform `acf` in the first `mutate...map`, and then extract `acf[1,,]` and `acf[2,,]` and convert to data frame in the second `mutate...map`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df1 %>% 
          group_by(Season) %>%
          nest() %>% 
          mutate(data = map(data, ~acf(., lag.max=1, type="correlation", plot=F))) %>%
          mutate(data = map(data, ~as.data.frame(rbind(.x$acf[1,,], .x$acf[2,,])))) %>%
          unnest(data)
```

The first 10 lines of output:

```
   Season            V1           V2           V3           V4            V5
 1 spring  1.000000e+00  0.999926654  0.888928901  0.999945732  0.9501684141
 2 spring  9.999267e-01  1.000000000  0.894411297  0.999998566  0.9463231324
 3 spring  8.889289e-01  0.894411297  1.000000000  0.893652539  0.7018425064
 4 spring  9.999457e-01  0.999998566  0.893652539  1.000000000  0.9468691987
 5 spring  9.501684e-01  0.946323132  0.701842506  0.946869199  1.0000000000
 6 spring -6.415051e-01 -0.649989355 -0.892898812 -0.648808668 -0.3899507753
 7 spring -6.360042e-01 -0.644491958 -0.888124854 -0.643310737 -0.3846451323
 8 spring -3.639938e-01 -0.371690371 -0.615653299 -0.370617371 -0.1470652339
 9 spring -6.367791e-01 -0.645266390 -0.888800271 -0.644085234 -0.3853904576
10 spring -7.499137e-01 -0.757869871 -0.969595555 -0.756763981 -0.5063447715
```

`summer` follows in the full data frame. The first `5 rows` of each `season` contain `acf[1,,]` and the following `5 rows` contain `acf[2,,]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works but I have a question here. My data are timeseries of many years and they are all daily values(the dataframe is large with many columns and I posted only 6 columns). It has a column for date. When I group them by seasons, how the lag correlations are computed? e.g. in a year, the end of spring is 31st May and the next day will be the 1st day of summer. Does this method take into account the sequence of original data for computing the lag correlations or it takes the sequence of data after grouping? This is not clear to me. Maybe you could help me in understanding this.

Comment: Computes lag correlations after grouping by `Season`.

Comment: Thanks again. This means I was thinking in wrong direction. Grouping is not the correct way to compute the lag correlations..maybe I should use for loop then.

Comment: Do you have better idea to compute the correlations without the use of for loop?

Comment: What you want now is probably different from what you described in your original post. Why not post another question? And highlight what you'd like as output...

Comment: Yes, I am relatively new to R  and I misunderstood it thinking that using group_by it can be done. Thanks..I will post soon.